# Please tell me how to view the data format of the realm database

Tags: database, realm

I want to see the data format in the realm database, but as shown above, it appears as '1190 bytes of data' and the binary value is not visible.
[image]
I looked up the db settings, but I couldn't see them.

Comment: The Data format? What do you mean exactly and why is that important? You can browse any local Realm Database File with [Realm Studio](https://github.com/realm/realm-studio/releases) and or can browse the sync Atlas data via the web console. Can you clarify the question and use case?

Comment: I opened the realm db file with the realm studio and inside, data as shown in the picture?The data in the format was shown as 'size byte of data'. I want to see the binary value for this in person. What should I do?

Comment: Looking at the image, it appears you're storing BLOB type data in Realm. While that's allowed as Realm supports NSData (Swift Data) types, it's not human readable. So your Realm Object has a property data which is optional and that's what's being stored. Are you looking for something more? e.g. if you want to Store a string, make the object property String. If you can clarify what's being asked and include your Realm Object model, we may be more help. See [Realm Property Types](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/define-model/supported-types/)